# Shiny: updateSelectInput does not update for different selectInput conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I am having issues updating the column names of a (optional) data frame in the sidebar, based on the chosen plottype in the first selectInput function.
The colnames are solely updated once, which means that the x-variables are only visible for the first plot type and the y- or distinguish-variables do only work for the second plot type. The third plottype does not offer any selections.

PS: I am new to stackoverflow as of today - I hope the example below provides enough info. Thanks in advance!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "plottype",
              label = "Choose your favorite plot type",
              choices = c("Histogram" = 1,
                          "Scatterplot" = 2,
                          "Whatever" = 3)),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.plottype == 1",
    selectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                label = "X-variable",
                choices = ""),
    uiOutput("choose_columns_1")),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.plottype == 2",
    selectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                label = "X-variable",
                choices = ""),
    selectInput(inputId = "y_var",
                label = "Y-variable",
                choices = ""),
    selectInput(inputId = "fill",
                label = "Distinguish",
                choices = ""),
    uiOutput("choose_columns_2")),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.plottype == 3",
    selectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                label = "X-variable",
                choices = ""),
    selectInput(inputId = "y_var",
                label = "Y-variable",
                choices = ""),
    selectInput(inputId = "fill",
                label = "Distinguish",
                choices = ""),
    uiOutput("choose_columns_3"))),

  mainPanel()
  )
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

getData <- reactive({
if(is.null(input$file1)) return(mtcars)
req(input$file1)
req(input$sep)
req(input$quote)
read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
         header = TRUE,
         sep = input$sep,
         quote = input$quote)
})

observe({
dsnames <- names(getData())
cb_options <- list()
cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames
updateSelectInput(session, "x_var",
                  label = "X-variable",
                  choices = cb_options,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "y_var",
                  label = "Y-variable",
                  choices = cb_options,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "fill",
                  label = "Distinguish",
                  choices = cb_options,
                  selected = "")
})



output$choose_columns_1 <- renderUI({
if(is.null(input$dataset))
  return()
colnames <- cb_options
updateSelectInput(session, "x_var",
                  label = "X-variable",
                  choices = colnames,
                  selected = "")
})


output$choose_columns_2 <- renderUI({
if(is.null(input$dataset))
  return()
colnames2 <- cb_options
updateSelectInput(session, "x_var",
                  label = "X-variable",
                  choices = colnames2,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "y_var",
                  label = "Y-variable",
                  choices = colnames2,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "fill",
                  label = "Distinguish",
                  choices = colnames2,
                  selected = "")
})

output$choose_columns_3 <- renderUI({
if(is.null(input$dataset))
  return()
colnames3 <- cb_options
updateSelectInput(session, "x_var",
                  label = "X-variable",
                  choices = colnames3,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "y_var",
                  label = "Y-variable",
                  choices = colnames3,
                  selected = "")
updateSelectInput(session, "fill",
                  label = "Distinguish",
                  choices = colnames3,
                  selected = "")
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: have you seen this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html and where is contents coming from?

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks for the comment! I've already seen the link above and my code also contains the observe function. I modified this code in your link by the assignment of the colnames because I want to dynamically change the colnames based on a data set the user can read in by his own. "Contents" is a leftover code content, which is now replaced by "cb_options" but still doesn't work.

Comment: if look at the documentation `updateSelectInput()` is not used inside a reactive argument

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Could you tell me more or give a short example? Thanks!

Comment: in `selectInput` you don't offer any choices. If you add choices, your code will work. IT is not clear why you need `updateSelectInput`.

Comment: I don't offer choices because I want to update them based on the csv file that is updated by the user. That's why I can't offer specific choices from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (using three datasets to simulate your needs):

```
data_sets <- c("mtcars", "morley", "rock")

ui = fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
       selectInput(inputId = "plottype",
                   label = "Choose your favorite plot type",
                   choices = c("Histogram" = 1,
                               "Scatterplot" = 2,
                               "Whatever" = 3)),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.plottype == 1", uiOutput("x_var")),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.plottype == 2 || input.plottype == 3",
       uiOutput("y_var"), uiOutput("fill"))

     ),
     mainPanel()
   )
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
     selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
   })


   output$x_var <- renderUI({
     # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
     if(is.null(input$dataset))
       return()

     # Get the data set with the appropriate name
     dat <- get(input$dataset)
     colnames <- names(dat)

     # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
     selectInput(inputId = "x_var",
                 label = "X-variable", 
                        choices  = colnames,
                        selected = colnames)
   })


   output$y_var <- renderUI({
     # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
     if(is.null(input$dataset))
       return()

     # Get the data set with the appropriate name
     dat <- get(input$dataset)
     colnames <- names(dat)

     # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
     selectInput(inputId = "y_var",
                 label = "Y-variable", 
                 choices  = colnames,
                 selected = colnames)
   })

   output$fill <- renderUI({
     # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
     if(is.null(input$dataset))
       return()

     # Get the data set with the appropriate name
     dat <- get(input$dataset)
     colnames <- names(dat)

     # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
     selectInput(inputId = "fill",
                 label = "Distinguish", 
                 choices  = colnames,
                 selected = colnames)
   })

}

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. My Problem is that it still doesn't work with the same uiOutput for different conditionalPanels. For example if you add `uiOutput("x_var")` to the last conditionalPanel (plottype 2 and 3) in the ui.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your original post. The code does what you asked. You can't use the same uiOutput twice.

Comment: Aahhhhh! I didn't know that I can't use the same uiOutput twice! Thank you so much! Helped a lot!